# How to match with an object value to print other values of same object

Tags: javascript

I have a variable x that contains an object ID "5ea151280d25c7310040677a". I also have an array in the following format

```
data = [
{_id: 5ea151280d25c7310040677a,
"name": "name7",
"codename": "mnoo7"
},
{_id: 5bg151280k25c7316640688a,
"name": "name8",
"codename": "mnoo8"
}
]
```

Now I want to return the name of this user that matches the object id in variable x.
So if x = 5ea151280d25c7310040677a I want to return name as name7
I have tried using indexof but no luck. any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Your object have typo issue, you can use `find` method as

```
let data = [
{_id: "ea151280d25c7310040677a",
name: "name7",
codename: "mnoo7"
},
{_id: "bg151280k25c7316640688a",
name: "name8",
codename: "mnoo8"
}
]

var found = data.find(c=>c._id == "ea151280d25c7310040677a");
console.log(found.name);
```

```js
let data = [
{_id: "ea151280d25c7310040677a",
name: "name7",
codename: "mnoo7"
},
{_id: "bg151280k25c7316640688a",
name: "name8",
codename: "mnoo8"
}
]

var found = data.find(c=>c._id == "ea151280d25c7310040677a");
console.log(found.name);
```